# ALERT! /dev/mapper/edbunto--g-root does not exist Error. Dropping to a Shell!

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

So I am stupidly new to `Linux`, like I wasn't even the one who installed it unto my computer.

I'm am using Ubuntu as the Linux software and I was tinkering around when I found something called `Disk creator` or something I cant remember what it was and I found a thing I believe it was called Hard Drive.

It had `80 gigabytes` of memory, and I double clicked it then I clicked on its settings and went to <kbd>advanced settings</kbd>.

It had a layout of devices from `01-05` and I clicked on device `01` and changed its partition from `Linux` to a `MAC OS X` partition.

Now mind you I don't have a clue at all what a partition is at the time when I did this, after that I rebooted my computer and gave me the following error and a gave me a very limited `BusyBox` and that's all I can go to after I choose a Ubuntu thing to load which is the `GNU GRUB version 2` and I've done so many things searched through thousands of links and can't find one solution that fits my problem.

I cant ever get past the `BusyBox` no matter what I've tried.

I've seen a lot of peoples problems are the same as mine but there solutions don't ever resolve the kind of problem here someone please help me! Id appreciate it thanks.

[image: 1]

Comment: This for some reason is not a solution to mine What idid was change the partition to a MAC OS X and now i cant use it at all it gives me a BusyBox with very limited commands

Comment: Change it back!